# HTML5 and geolocation

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I want to get my position each timeinterval using `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition`
Later on I want to store these coordinates in a xml file.

The problem is the `watchPosition` function does not call the `getLocation` function.

```
  function trackCoords ()
  {
      if (navigator.geolocation)
      {

          var options = { frequency: 3000 };
            watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(getLocation, locationFail, options);
      }


  }



  function getLocation(position) { 
        alert();
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        alert('latitude: ' + latitude + ' longitude: ' + longitude);
        }

    function locationFail() {
    document.write('We did not get your location');
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not calling trackCoords. Does the browser ask you for permission to be geolocalized? If I add `trackCoords()` at the end of your script it seems to work for me:

http://codepen.io/jonigiuro/pen/vCBsk

Comment: I'm calling trackCoords() in another piece of code wich i thought was irrelevant.

$('#track').click(trackCoords);
I've tested with an alert(), and trackCoords() does get called but the code is not working.
But when I put trackCoords() at the bottom of my document the code works my browser asks permission to be geolocalized.

Comment: The javascript should be at the bottom of your document, just before the closing body tag, otherwise you're trying to bind a click event to an element that doesn't exist, in this case $('#track').click(trackCoords); The page loads from top to bottom, so when it reaches this cose, the #track element is not yet there. Another fix would be to wrap that code around a $(document).ready(function() { /*your code here*/ }), this will only execute when the dom is loaded

Comment: $('#track').click(trackCoords); 
is already in a ready function.

Should i use an setTimeout to track the coordinates after x seconds?
or does the watchposition only work when your position is changed?

Comment: ok Now I understand the problem: by looking here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.watchPosition I see that watchPosition will call the other function only when the position changes, so you'll have to walk around with your mobile phone to test this. Or use a setInterval to force to get the position, like this http://codepen.io/jonigiuro/pen/zpmvB

Comment: Yes i've tried that before, and it works the same like yours.
But when i walk around for like 50meters it show the same coordinate then when i started walking.

Comment: Precision of my actual GPS? or from my mobile network?

Comment: I don't know, one of the two. Try walking around and manually calling   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options) and see if the value changes